# How to configure jhipster app to run on different port when launching with maven

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, jhipster

[Jhipster docs](http://jhipster.github.io/production.html) say you have to

`mvn -Pprod package`

and then you can execute the generated war with

`java -jar jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war --spring.profiles.active=prod`

you may configure the server port with

`java -jar jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war --spring.profiles.active=prod --server.port=9000`

as per the [Spring Boot docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) specify that command line arguments take precedence over application properties files and YAML variants.

But, when trying to **run the app with maven on a different port**

> `mvn -Pprod -Dserver.port=9000 spring-boot:run`

it **still reads the server.port from application-prod.yml**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> mvn -Pprod spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="--server.port=9000,--spring.profiles.active=prod"

Comment: I wish it would have worked, unfortunately it didn't. I've created a new jhipster project with default options and tried to run this command but it still runs on server.port configured on application-{profile}.yml.
I've also tried
`export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dserver.port=9000" && mvn spring-boot:run`
but it didn't work either :(
For the moment I'll keep packaging first and then run the `java -jar jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war --server.port=9000`

Comment: So sorry. I incorrectly assumed ```mvn -Pprod spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments='-Dserver.port=9000'``` would work. I've updated my answer to what works for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="--server.port=9090"

Answer (score 0):

For me, passing the SERVER_PORT as env variable worked:

```
SERVER_PORT=9000 mvn spring-boot:run
```

Spring translates the os env variables `SERVER_PORT` into spring's `server.port` configuration.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files